# React-Native: LayoutAnimation

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native's LayoutAnimation to implement a custom switch component.

[image]

I am animating the movement of the circle using LayoutAnimation like so:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
  let switchAnimation = {
    duration: 250,
     update: {
       type: LayoutAnimation.Types.linear,
       property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity,
     },
  };
  LayoutAnimation.configureNext(switchAnimation);
}
```

The switch is its own component. It recieves props to set the circle to be on the left or right using css (justifyContent flex-start or flex-end)

Problem is in my view when the switch changes value other components change as well: Namely when the switch is hit:

1) Switch changes

2) An icon changes

3) Some text changes

All of the above animate. I want to reduce the animation to affect the switch only

**UPDATE**: I have tried using the Animated API but it doesnt seem to support animating flex properties. Is there really no one out there that uses The Animated API extensively?

Comment: LayoutAnimation is not the right way here.  Consider using Animated API https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html

Comment: The example in the docs uses the components state. How will that work in my case? Should i map a prop to a state variable and create an animation from there?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example which includes using the Animated API with the `flex` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LayoutAnimation does a lot under the hood. Unless you are willing to go through the source you can set and vary a margin value in order to move the circle in the container. You can make all the calculations within the component and expose some styles as props.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the only viable solution

Answer (score -2):

This issue is caused because the wrong animation solution is being used.

To animate a specific element, use the [Animated API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated), not the [LayoutAnimation API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation).

Learn more about the differences in the [Animations Guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations).

I learned this difference when attempting to animate a progress bar using the `flex` property with a value in the range 0 to 1.

Here's some sample code, edited to remove unreleated project-specifics…

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Animated, View } from 'react-native'
const progressStyles = {
  height: 10,
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
}
class PasswordStrengthMeter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    width: new Animated.Value(0), // value in the range 0–1
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.score !== this.props.score) {
      Animated.timing(this.state.width, {
        toValue: nextProps.score / 4, // score will be a value between 0-4
        duration: 500,
      }).start()
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            progressStyles,
            {
              flex: this.state.width, // value in the range 0–1
            },
          ]}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```